# Fixing 'Input/output error' from .bashrc in Windows Subsystem for Linux

Tags: windows, bash, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I mistakenly edited the `.bashrc` file for my WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux) Bash using a Windows text editor (Notepad++).

Now whenever I run Bash I get the following error:

> bash: /root/.bashrc: Input/output error

How can I fix this? I tried saving with Linux file endings (LF only) but that didn't work.

Comment: I'm curious how exactly you broke it, because I can't seem to replicate (despite this being a known bad idea). Also, what version of Windows are you running? 1703? 1709? Older? My general idea for fixing it and preserving file contents (in a generic way) was to read it on the Windows side, base64 it, and write it back on the WSL side. Untested until I can reproduce the issue...

Comment: I opened it up in NotePad++, commented 3 lines at the end and saved it. That was enough to corrupt it. Did not make any deliberate changes to EOL or encoding.

Comment: My case had the same error msg but with a different cause: a google search pointed me to this issue ["Unlink syscall does not allow file to be reopened after"](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/1357) which lead me for this temporal workaround: just restart wsl with `wsl --shutdown`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've found a minimal solution to my problem. My WSL is running Ubuntu. In Ubuntu there is a pristine copy of `.bashrc` under `/etc/skel`.

1. I deleted my bad copy of `.bashrc` using Windows Explorer.
2. In Bash I copied over the pristine copy like so:
   `cp /etc/skel/.bashrc ~/`

(Based on this AskUbuntu answer: https://askubuntu.com/questions/198730/how-to-restore-bashrc-file)

Comment: Note: all existing bash shells must be closed before the file delete is registered https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/904#issuecomment-293819387

Answer (score 4):

#### How can I fix this? I tried saving with Linux file endings (LF only) but that didn't work.

There are a couple of solutions:

> Use a Linux / Ubuntu app to modify files these files (vim, emacs, nano, etc...).

One person said editing with `nano` and re-saving the file fixed the issue.

If that doesn't work you can try the nuclear option of re-installing:

> In my case, nothing got it fixed. I used following command to delete
>   BashOnWindows and then reinstall it:
>
> ```
> lxrun /uninstall /full
>
> lxrun /install /y
> ```

Source [bash command not work for me after edit .bashrc using ST3](https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/904)

---

#### Further Reading

- [WSL File System Support](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wsl/2016/06/15/wsl-file-system-support/)
- [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zd8nJUbYpxs) is a nice whiteboard-talk about how WSL/LXSS works and why editing/copying files and moving them into the VolFS mounts won't always work. See in particular [15:15 in the video](https://youtu.be/Zd8nJUbYpxs?t=15m15s)

Comment: I nearly crossed with your answer, yet again! @urig's own answer confirms your diagnosis.

Comment: Thanks @DavidPostill but your first suggestions did not work because WSL was unable to recognize the bad `.bashrc` file. The last suggestion is quite aggressive in that it completely reinstalls WSL. Luckily I managed to solve using a simpler, quicker operation -  See my own answer to my question.

Comment: @urig Great! Good job you hadn't personalised the file though ...

Comment: FYI `lxrun` is deprecated as of 1709. `wslconfig` is the new CLI tool, while the Store is the correct place to install/uninstall distros. See: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/commandline/2017/10/11/whats-new-in-wsl-in-windows-10-fall-creators-update/